# Joomla Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, joomla, sass

I have very little php knowledge. I know I'm doing something wrong, but what?

I'm adding the sass compiler from Joomla Master Bootstrap template into my own Joomla template. It works, but not as it should. I can't turn it on or off in the backend. 
The code in Masterbootstrap is this:

```
include 'includes/params.php';
if ($params->get('compile_sass', '0') === '1') {
    require_once "includes/sass.php";
}
```

In my template I don't have params.php, but /functions/tpl-init.php. I added the variable $compile_sass there. My code looks like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions/tpl-init.php';
if ($params->get('compile_sass', '0') === '1') {
    require_once "includes/html/sass.php";
}
```

Doesn't work. I get the error: Call to a member function get() on null

So I changed this into:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions/tpl-init.php';
require_once "includes/html/sass.php";
```

That works, but now the compiler is permanently on.

What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

To get template params from outside the template you need to do this

Template parameters from outside a template

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site'); 
$temp = $app->getTemplate(true); 
$param = $temp->params->get('compile_sass', '0');
```

Remember the Masterbootstrap template should be active.

To get any template param you need to do this

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query  ->select('params')
        ->from('#__template_styles')
        ->where('`template` = ' . $db->q('masterbootstrap')) // Check Spelling of template
        ->where('client_id = 0'); // client_id = 0 for Site and client_id = 1 for Admin
$db->setQuery($query);
$params = json_decode($db->loadResult());
echo $params->compile_sass;
```

Better is to create a similar param in your own template using your templateDetails.xml file rather than depending on the external template.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a friend. He solved it in a minute. It's so simple... it usually is, after you found the solution:

```
    require_once __DIR__ . '/functions/tpl-init.php';
    if ($compile_sass === '1')
    {
    require_once "includes/html/sass.php";
    }
```